# CSS: Background crashes on mobile devices only

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, background

As this is my first post here, I would like to apologize if I did something wrong with this thread.

**About the problem:** I have a problem with the background when I go to my website, but it appears only when I open it on mobile device. The website is [www.mistralgroup.eu](http://www.mistralgroup.eu) (It's in bulgarian, but I hope you get the idea)

You can check it and you will see what I mean - everything is fine and it works properly until I try to open in on my mobile device. Then 3 boxes with the main image are okay, but there is an orange container between boxes and footer, which is actually the background. But why it appears only when I use it on mobile? I tried different combinations, but it just doesn't work. I know it's not a hard to solve problem, but it makes me nervous.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Comment: that orange field is present on mobile and on laptop iether. maybe it is very short and you can't see it?

Comment: Please do not link to websites and ask us to look up the code there. The problem is that once you fix the problem, your question becomes useless to others. Instead, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, but I don't really know where is the problem. Do I have to put the entire code? I am not sure if it comes from background or boxes or containers. I think it's related to "bottom property" somehow, but that's why I posted the link directly. Sorry.

Comment: Your website is not at all mobile responsive, if u can't post the code, try solving issue on your part by using media queries, here is reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score -1):

Your website is not Responsive. That is the problem. The orange part is present in mobile view but u have scroll to right to see it.

Comment: I am not sure, that this is the reason. There are a lot of non-responsible websites, but there isn't the same problem. I think I have made a mistake somewhere deep in my code, but I can't find it.